# How to call filterHandler manually in element-ui?

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

While loading a page, I need to default check some filtered condition. I have set the default value by this.$refs.tableRC.columns[0].filteredValue = this.filteredBranch, but I have no idea how to call filterHandler() manually to filter the table data?

```
<el-table ref="tableRC" :data="datalist" @filter-change="tableFilter">
  <el-table-column label="Branch" :filters="branches" :column-key="'branch'" :filter-method="filterHandler">
```

......

```
tableFilter(filters) {
  this.filteredBranch = filters.branch
},
filterHandler(value, row, column) {
  return row.branch === value
},
getReqList() {
  ....
  this.$refs.tableRC.columns[0].filteredValue = this.filteredBranch
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution

```
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(this.filteredBranch) === '[object Array]') {
      this.$refs.tableRC.columns[x].filteredValue = this.filteredBranch
      this.$refs.tableRC.store.states.columns.forEach(column=> {           
        if (column.filteredValue && column.filteredValue.length) {
          this.$refs.tableRC.store.commit('filterChange', {
            column,
            values: column.filteredValue,
            silent: true
          })
        }
      })
    }
```